# Find a string and replace in all files inside a directory and sub-directory

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep, find

I am thinking to replace a string in linux, the idea is to find all files having abc as string and replace with xyz inside a directory and all sub-directories.

Can you suggest how can I do this with Linux shell scripting

Comment: `find` + `sed`. What have you attempted, why does it not work?

Comment: i have tried grep -l -r with sed 
But the changes seems to be improper 
When i use sed finding a error sed: couldn't edit : not a regular file

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include all details.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files

Answer (score 1):

You can use find and sed, since sed will only affect files which have this string. If a file does not have the string, there's no disadvantage of running the replace anyway:

```
find -type f -exec sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g' {} +
```

- `-type f` only find files (exclude directories)
- `-exec` for each file found execute …
- `sed -i` edit files in-place
- `s/abc/xyz/g` replace all occurrences of "abc" with "xyz" in all lines
- `{} +` invoke the "exec" command with multiple file names at once, instead of once per file

Comment: shouldn't the sed command be 's/abc/xyz/g'?

Comment: @AMS yes, thank you! The explanation was correct, but the full code block was incorrect. Thanks for noticing!